# Is it better to use Enumerable.Empty<T>() as opposed to new List<T>() to initialize an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, constructor

Suppose you have a class Person :

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<Role> Roles {get; set;}
}
```

I should obviously instantiate the Roles in the constructor.
Now, I used to do it with a List like this :

```
public Person()
{
   Roles = new List<Role>();
}
```

But I discovered this static method in the `System.Linq` namespace

```
IEnumerable<T> Enumerable.Empty<T>();
```

**From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx):**

> The `Empty(TResult)()` method caches an
>   empty sequence of type `TResult`. When
>   the object it returns is enumerated,
>   it yields no elements.
>
> In some cases, this method is useful
>   for passing an empty sequence to a
>   user-defined method that takes an
>   `IEnumerable(T)`. It can also be used to
>   generate a neutral element for methods
>   such as `Union`. See the Example section
>   for an example of this use of

So is it better to write the constructor like that? Do you use it? Why? or if not, Why not?

```
public Person()
{
   Roles = Enumerable.Empty<Role>();
}
```

Comment: This is a Data class. I intend to use this class as a Model class when implementing a repository pattern with Entity Framework 4.0 (playing around...). so I think it's fine to have a public setter here, isn't it?

Comment: serbech, how will you Add a role (inside Person) when other code can installed any kind of IEnumerable derived class for the list? What will you cast it to?

Comment: I see your point, I should probably have a IList internally, or even a List here?
And that would just remove my original problem...

Comment: I use Enumerable.Empty<T> in unit testing to indicate unhappy path tests to help communicate the intent. As many have already pointed it out the bonus is no allocation on the GC which helps when your unit tests number in the hundreds or more.

Comment: I agree that you'd want to remove the `set` and just use the `IList` interface directly.  If however you want to keep it as `IEnumerable` with the `set`, *really* it seems you should init it to `null`.  Just the same way you don't need to init `Name` to an empty string--since it's got a `set`, you just init to `null` and have the client code `set` it.

Comment: Now one can also use `Array.Empty<Role>()` which is explicitly an array and hence an `IList<T>`. In Core it's in fact the same array, with only the type exposed differing.

Comment: This is probably long overdue, but if you don't need the indexer `[]` you might be better off using `ICollection<T>` instead of `IList<T>`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855693/returning-ilist-vs-icollection-vs-collection#9855734

Answer (score 259, accepted):

I think most postings missed the main point. Even if you use an empty array or empty list, those are objects and they are stored in memory. The Garbage Collector has to take care of them. If you are dealing with a high throughput application, it could be a noticeable impact.

`Enumerable.Empty` does not create an object per call thus putting less load on the GC.

If the code is in low-throughput location, then it boils down to aesthetic considerations though.

Comment: And it's also reflecting the intention better.

Comment: How does `Empty()` work if it does not create no object?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin it return singleton

Comment: Not only does `Enumerable.Empty<>` return a singleton enumerable, that enumerable also returns a singleton enumerator.

Comment: I don't think this is correct anymore, as [`Enumerable.Empty<>` now just returns `Array.Empty<>`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/8e51ee0bbd2979a15b361f4abfd95e1b2e4b2935).

Comment: @Lennart I do not think so. The code you provided makes use of `Array.Empty<TResult>()` which is a function and not a constructor. And this function returns `EmptyArray<T>.Value` which in its turn use ` public static readonly T[] Value = new T[0];` So singleton used has been changed, but it is still a singleton.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. Should've checked the `Empty<TResult>()` function beforehand.

Answer (score 118):

I think `Enumerable.Empty<T>` is better because it is more explicit: your code clearly indicates your intentions. It might also be a bit more efficient, but that's only a secondary advantage.

Comment: Yes, making it clear that you mean this to be empty vs. something that might be added to later is good for your code.

Comment: Yes. Enumerable<>.Empty does avoid allocating a new object, which is a small bonus.

Comment: sidenote @NeilWhitaker: it's Enumerable.Empty<T> not Enumerable<T>.Empty (that one drove me crazy once...)

Comment: Agreed. To add; if you need to initialize an `IEnumerable<T>`...why initialize it with more firepower than you need. `List<T>` is a more complex object which implements `IEnumerable<T>`, among many other things. I say initialize properties in the most basic way possible and use `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` in this case as well.

Answer (score 36):

On the performance front, let's see how `Enumerable.Empty<T>` is implemented.

It returns `EmptyEnumerable<T>.Instance`, which is defined as:

```
internal class EmptyEnumerable<T>
{
    public static readonly T[] Instance = new T[0];
}
```

Static fields on generic types are allocated per generic type parameter. This means that the runtime can lazily create these empty arrays only for the types user code needs, and reuse the instances as many times as needed without adding any pressure on the garbage collector.

To wit:

```
Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(Enumerable.Empty<int>(), Enumerable.Empty<int>()));
```

Comment: All this while I thought the implementation was like `public static IEnumerable<T> Empty<T>() 
    {
        yield break;
    }`

MS knows it best, probably a cached `new T[0]` is more efficient.

Comment: Verified, the implementation is the same in .NET Core 2.2 (just the class names are different).

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you actually want to populate the `Roles` property somehow, then encapsulate that by making it's setter private and initialising it to a new list in the constructor:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Role> Roles { get; private set; }

    public Person()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
    }
}
```

If you really really want to have the public setter, leave `Roles` with a value of `null` and avoid the object allocation.

Comment: I would recommend `ICollection` over `IList`

Comment: You should never let collections be null. It provides no benefit and only leads to senselessly needing additional null checks all over your code, or worse, exceptions due to forgetting these. Initializing it with `Enumerable.Empty<string>()` or `Array.Empty<string>()` likewise also avoids object allocations.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with your approach is that you can't add any items to the collection - I would have a private structure like list and then expose the items as an Enumerable:

```
public class Person
{
    private IList<Role> _roles;

    public Person()
    {
        this._roles = new List<Role>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void AddRole(Role role)
    {
        //implementation
    }

    public IEnumerable<Role> Roles
    {
        get { return this._roles.AsEnumerable(); }
    }
}
```

If you intend some other class to create the list of roles (which I wouldn't recommend) then I wouldn't initialise the enumerable at all in Person.

Comment: that's a good point. I would have find that out quickly in my implementation in fact :)

Comment: I would make _roles readonly, and I don't see the need for the call to AsEnumerable(). Otherwise, +1

Comment: @Kent - I agree with readonly. As for AsEnumerable, it's not really needed but it prevents Roles being cast to IList and modified.

Answer (score 7):

The typical problem with exposing the private List as an IEnumerable is that the client of your class can mess with it by casting.  This code would work:

```
  var p = new Person();
  List<Role> roles = p.Roles as List<Role>;
  roles.Add(Role.Admin);
```

You can avoid this by implementing an iterator:

```
public IEnumerable<Role> Roles {
  get {
    foreach (var role in mRoles)
      yield return role;
  }
}
```

Comment: If a developer casts your IEnumerable<T> to a List<T>, then that's his problem and not yours. If you change the internal implementation in the future (so it's no longer List<T>), it's not your fault that the developer's code breaks. You can't stop people from writing crappy code and abusing your API, so I don't think it's worth spending a lot of effort on.

Comment: This is not about breaking code, it is about exploiting code.

Comment: I agree with @Hans if it's a security concern, and with @Tommy in all other cases. Naughty developers always make that one fatal mistake.

Comment: And the enumeration part can be writter using the AsEnumerable() extension method. (similar to Lee's answer)

Comment: @Stephane no, because `AsEnumerable()` will just give you the `List<T>` again, so if you're hoping to guarantee it can't be cast back, you've gained nothing.