# What ReadOnlyCollection type should methods return?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

I've seen [Returning 'IList' vs 'ICollection' vs 'Collection'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855693/ilist-vs-icollection-vs-collection) and the other questions that it links to, but I'm still confused about this issue.

Let's assume for demonstration purposes that I have a class, where I expose a public method, as follows:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<Type> GetReadOnlyCollection(IEnumerable<Type> enumerable)
{
    List<Type> list = enumerable.ToList();
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<Type>(list);
}
```

To follow [CA1002](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182142.aspx), should my method return the *actual collection classes* (`ReadOnlyCollection`, `Collection`, etc.) or *their interfaces* (`IList`, `ICollection`, etc.) if I wish to return a `ReadOnlyCollection` specifically?

Comment: There is no "one answer".  But, in general, you should program to an interface rather than a specific class.  IMHO...

Comment: It depends I guess, if you intend the classes to be reused/derived then yes to Interfaces, otherwise the main concern would be performance. IMO

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use IList and when to use List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170/when-to-use-ilist-and-when-to-use-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original question was not super well-defined; there are a number of considerations that should be taken into account:

- Does the user only need to enumerate through the code? If so, `IEnumerable` is probably enough.
- Should the user know that the collection is intended to be read-only? If so, `IReadOnlyCollection` is probably fine.
- Do you want to prevent the user from casting your read-only collection to a mutable type? If so, use an immutable collection from `System.Collections.Immutable`.

Some useful answers are in these questions:

- [ReadOnlyCollection or IEnumerable for exposing member collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491375/readonlycollection-or-ienumerable-for-exposing-member-collections)
- [IEnumerable vs IReadonlyCollection vs ReadonlyCollection for exposing a list member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880268/ienumerable-vs-ireadonlycollection-vs-readonlycollection-for-exposing-a-list-mem)

Answer (score 1):

You gain flexibility to later change the implementation if you return a type as general as possible. But of course you have to return a type that is useful for the consumer. Hence, generally returning the interface type is better, and the more general type as well, as long as this does not cause any problems in usage on consumer side.