# Using IReadOnlyCollection<T> instead of IEnumerable<T> for parameters to avoid possible multiple enumeration

Tags: c#, resharper, .net-4.5, ienumerable, readonly-collection

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24880268/197591) concerning the use of `IEnumerable<T>` vs `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

I too have always used `IEnumerable<T>` to expose collections as both return types and parameters because it benefits from being both immutable and lazily executed.

However, I am becoming increasingly concerned about the proliferation of places in my code where I must enumerate a parameter to avoid the possible multiple enumeration warning that ReSharper gives. I understand why ReSharper suggests this, and I agree with the code it suggests (below) in order to ensure encapsulation (i.e., no assumptions about the caller).

```
 Foo[] arr = col as Foo[] ?? col.ToArray();
```

However, I find the repetitiveness of this code pollutive, and I agree with some sources that `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` is a better alternative, particularly the points made in [this article](http://www.fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2012/07/23/IReadOnlyCollectionlt;Tgt;-Improves-IEnumerablelt;Tgt;-as-a-Return-Type.aspx), which states:

> Lately, I’ve been considering the merits and demerits of returning
>   `IEnumerable<T>`.
>
> On the plus side, it is about as minimal as an interface gets, so it
>   leaves you as method author more flexibility than committing to a
>   heavier alternative like `IList<T>` or ([heaven forbid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx)) an array.
>
> However, as I outlined in [the last post](http://www.fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2012/07/22/LINQ-Entices-Liskov-Violations.aspx), an `IEnumerable<T>` return
>   entices callers to violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://www.fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2012/04/08/Refactoring-to-SOLID-Part-4-The-Liskov-Substitution-Principle.aspx). It’s too
>   easy for them to use LINQ extension methods like `Last()` and `Count()`,
>   whose semantics `IEnumerable<T>` does not promise.
>
> What’s needed is a better way to lock down a returned collection
>   without making such temptations so prominent. (I am reminded of Barney
>   Fife learning this lesson the hard way.)
>
> Enter [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542(v=vs.110).aspx), new in .NET 4.5. It adds just one
>   property to `IEnumerable<T>`: the `Count` property. By promising a count,
>   you assure your callers that your `IEnumerable<T>` really does have a
>   terminus. They can then use LINQ extension methods like `Last()` with a
>   clear conscience.

However, as the observant may have noticed, this article only talks about using `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` for return types. My question is, would the same arguments equally apply to using it for parameters also? Any theoretical thoughts or comments on this would also be appreciated.

In fact, I'm thinking a general rule of thumb to use `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` would be where there would be possible multiple enumeration (vis-à-vis the ReSharper warning) if `IEnumerable<T>` is used. Otherwise, use `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: There is an attribute in resharper's annotations called `[NoEnumeration]` well its just an attribute but its there saying `Indicates that IEnumerable, passed as parameter, is not enumerated.` it does nothing but I used it because its cool

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, that's cool, and useful I guess where you're not enumerating the `IEnumerable`. But my question is wider than that use case, and more about where the `IEnumerable` *is* enumerated. Is `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` a better alternative in these cases, for the reasons I mentioned (i.e., the points made in the article)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having thought about this further, I have come to the conclusion, based on the article I mentioned in my Question, that it is indeed OK to use `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` as a parameter, but only in functions where it will definitely be enumerated.  If enumeration is conditional based on other parameters, object state, or workflow, then it should still be passed in as `IEnumerable<T>` so that lazy evaluation is semantically ensured.