# Using ReadOnlyCollection<T> vs List<T> vs array for return types

Tags: c#, arrays, list, return-type, readonly-collection

I posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41264238/197591) a while ago concerning parameters, and it referred to [an article](http://www.fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2012/07/22/LINQ-Entices-Liskov-Violations.aspx) more pertinent to *this* question, which advocates using `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` over `IEnumerable<T>`.

> Lately, I’ve been considering the merits and demerits of returning
> `IEnumerable<T>`.
>
> On the plus side, it is about as minimal as an interface gets, so it
> leaves you as method author more flexibility than committing to a
> heavier alternative like `IList<T>` or ([heaven forbid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fss9skc.aspx)) an array.
>
> However, as I outlined in [the last post](http://www.fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2012/07/22/LINQ-Entices-Liskov-Violations.aspx), an `IEnumerable<T>` return
> entices callers to violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://www.fascinatedwithsoftware.com/blog/post/2012/04/08/Refactoring-to-SOLID-Part-4-The-Liskov-Substitution-Principle.aspx). It’s too
> easy for them to use LINQ extension methods like `Last()` and `Count()`,
> whose semantics `IEnumerable<T>` does not promise.
>
> What’s needed is a better way to lock down a returned collection
> without making such temptations so prominent. (I am reminded of Barney
> Fife learning this lesson the hard way.)
>
> Enter [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542(v=vs.110).aspx), new in .NET 4.5. It adds just one
> property to `IEnumerable<T>`: the `Count` property. By promising a count,
> you assure your callers that your `IEnumerable<T>` really does have a
> terminus. They can then use LINQ extension methods like `Last()` with a
> clear conscience.

However, [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20201027094654/http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/11/04/c.net-fundamentals-returning-an-immutable-collection.aspx) advocates using `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` (and other alternatives) for the case where you want to protect members.

So, I discussed this with a colleague, and we have different opinions.

He suggests that a method should return whatever it has (such as a `List<T>` or array) if the method produced it and the caller changing it afterwards would have no effect on anything else (i.e., it's not a member and doesn't belong to anything whose lifetime is greater than the method call).

My view is that `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` indicates to the caller that the collection should typically remain as is. If they want to change it, then the onus is on them to explicitly cast it to a `IList<T>` or call `ToList` on it.

The [Microsoft guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections) in particular state:

> In general, prefer `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

But it doesn't seem to define the general case other than stating to use `Collection<T>` for returning read/write collections. But is my colleague's view that the consumer *might* want to add to the collection and that we don't care if they do the definition for returning a read/write collection, or not?

**EDIT**

In answer to some of the replies, to try and add more context to my question, I've placed some code below demonstrate various scenarios with comments relating to my question:

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly int[] array = { 1 };
    private readonly List<int> list = new List<int>(new[] {1});

    // Get member array.
    public int[] GetMemberArrayAsIs() => array;

    public IEnumerable<int> GetMemberArrayAsEnumerable() => array;

    public ReadOnlyCollection<int> GetMemberArrayAsReadOnlyCollection() => new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(array);

    // Get local array.
    public int[] GetLocalArrayAsIs() => new[] { 1 };

    public IEnumerable<int> GetLocalArrayAsEnumerable() => new[] { 1 };

    public ReadOnlyCollection<int> GetLocalArrayAsReadOnlyCollection() => new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(new[] { 1 });

    // Get member list.
    public Collection<int> GetMemberListAsIs() => new Collection<int>(list);

    public IEnumerable<int> GetMemberListAsEnumerable() => array;

    public ReadOnlyCollection<int> GetMemberListAsReadOnlyCollection() => new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(array);

    // Get local list.
    public Collection<int> GetLocalListAsIs() => new Collection<int>(new[] { 1 });

    public IEnumerable<int> GetLocalListAsEnumerable() => new List<int>(new[] { 1 });

    public ReadOnlyCollection<int> GetLocalListAsReadOnlyCollection() => new List<int>(new[] { 1 }).AsReadOnly();
}


class FooTest
{
    void Test()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        int count;

        // Get member array.
        var array1 = foo.GetMemberArrayAsIs(); // ReSharper encourages to make the return type IEnumerable<T>.
        count = array1.Length;  // ...unless we do this.

        var enumerable1 = foo.GetMemberArrayAsEnumerable();
        enumerable1.Concat(enumerable1); // Warning of possible multiple enumeration.

        var roc1 = foo.GetMemberArrayAsReadOnlyCollection(); // ReSharper encourages to make the return type IEnumerable<T>.
        count = roc1.Count;  // ...unless we do this.


        // Get local array.
        var array2 = foo.GetLocalArrayAsIs(); // ReSharper encourages to make the return type IEnumerable<T>.
        count = array2.Length;  // ...unless we do this.

        var enumerable2 = foo.GetLocalArrayAsEnumerable();
        enumerable2.Concat(enumerable2); // Warning of possible multiple enumeration.

        var roc2 = foo.GetLocalArrayAsReadOnlyCollection(); // ReSharper encourages to make the return type IEnumerable<T>.
        count = roc2.Count;  // ...unless we do this.


        // Get member list.
        var list1 = foo.GetMemberListAsIs(); // ReSharper encourages to make the return type IEnumerable<T>.
        count = list1.Count;  // ...unless we do this.
        list1.Add(2); // This affects the Foo object as the collection is a member. DANGEROUS!

        var enumerable3 = foo.GetMemberListAsEnumerable();
        enumerable3.Concat(enumerable3); // Warning of possible multiple enumeration.

        var roc3 = foo.GetMemberListAsReadOnlyCollection(); // ReSharper encourages to make the return type IEnumerable<T>.
        count = roc3.Count;  // ...unless we do this.


        // Get local list.
        var list2 = foo.GetLocalListAsIs(); // ReSharper encourages to make the return type IEnumerable<T>.
        count = list2.Count;  // ...unless we do this.
        list2.Add(2); // This doesn't affect the Foo object as the collection was produced by the method.

        var enumerable4 = foo.GetLocalListAsEnumerable();
        enumerable4.Concat(enumerable4); // Warning of possible multiple enumeration.

        var roc4 = foo.GetLocalListAsReadOnlyCollection(); // ReSharper encourages to make the return type IEnumerable<T>.
        count = roc4.Count;  // ...unless we do this.
    }
}
```

So to use an example to demonstrate the dilemma, if we take `GetMemberArrayAsIs`, ReSharper tells me to change the return type to `IEnumerable<T>` if the calling code enumerates the returned value only once. If I enumerate the returned value more than once, then I must leave it as it is in order to avoid the possible multiple enumeration warning.  However, this is where my question comes in.  Instead of returning the array, should I return `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` to comply with my understanding of the Microsoft guidelines?  This would require me to instantiate a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` as shown in `GetMemberArrayAsReadOnlyCollection`.  Or, should we just return the array as is as my colleague believes (`GetMemberArrayAsIs`)?

Alternatively, I could insist on returning `IEnumerable<T>` and put the onus on the caller to enumerate before using the collection multiple times, but I think Microsoft's preference to use `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is to avoid exactly this.

In the case of a `List<T>`, the dilemma is slightly more complicated because of the possibility it can be changed which is a problem if it's a member.  In this case, I should certainly return a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` (`GetMemberListAsReadOnlyCollection`).  But in the case of a local list, should I return `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` to comply with my understanding of the Microsoft guidelines?  This would require me to instantiate a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` as shown in `GetLocalListAsReadOnlyCollection`.  Or, should we just return the list as is as my colleague believes (`GetMemberListAsIs`)?

I hope this adds more context to the question, and it's fairly philosophical in some respects.  But a lot of it is about how the Microsoft guidelines should be interpreted, and whether the onus should be put on the provider to convert to `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, or for the consumer to enumerate the returned value before using multiple times (using `ToArray`), or indeed neither and returning as is.

Comment: Too vague - returning **from what**? How you should write code depends on the context, the intended users, scope etc. so any single rule will be worse than useless.

Comment: @buffjape OK, I've added more information to the question including code.

Answer (score 7):

This question might get closed because it's vague and there is no single correct answer, but I'll try anyway.

I would say, if you return an object that is a `List<T>` or `T[]`, you may want to expose it as at least `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` or better [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx) which has indexer support. The advantages of doing this is:

- A call to `ToList` is not required to do multiple enumerations of the same output.
- The boundaries are clearly defined
- Using an `IReadOnlyList<T>`, you could enumerate with a `for` loop as opposed to `foreach`, which might be advantageous in some corner cases.

The main disadvantage I see of this, which could be a big one depending on the implementation:

- Your API will no longer be able to return an `IEnumerable<T>` in a streaming fashion (e.g. reading from a `Stream` or `IDbDataReader`, etc). This would mean introducing a breaking change in your code.

As for using `IList<T>` vs `IReadOnlyList<T>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, this should be perfectly fine as long as you're ok always returning a copy of the list. If you have a list that you keep around in memory you wouldn't want the caller to modify it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated the question with context and some code to make it more clear. Maybe you can revise your answer now?