# What's the difference between IList and ICollection?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist

Can anyone elaborate on IList and ICollection. And also, When and where do we use IList or ICollection

Comment: See the answers in: [IList vs ICollection vs Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855693/ilist-vs-icollection-vs-collection)

Comment: @cubrr so, it isnt a dupe, or we should flag/close as dupe?

Answer (score 9):

`IList` implements `ICollection` and `IEnumerable`. In addition it provides method definitions for adding and removing elements and to clear the collection. It also provides methods for handling the positioning of the elements within the collection. It also provides an object indexer to allow the user to access the collection with square brackets like:

```
myList[elementIndex]
```

[image]

reference: [Claudio Bernasconi's article about IList and ICollection](http://www.claudiobernasconi.ch/2013/07/22/when-to-use-ienumerable-icollection-ilist-and-list/)