# Why use ICollection<T> over IList<T>?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, icollection

I've read articles that say use `ICollection<T>` if you want the functionality of `IEnumerable<T>`, but also want the `Count` property.

However since the extension methods in `System.Linq.Enumerable` provide methods such as `ElementAt()`, why wouldn't you just use an `IList<T>` instead, since that uses an indexer?

Seems to me that `ICollection<T>` can do what `IList<T>` can do, just in a much more verbose and less readable way.

What scenario would it be more readable/more efficent, more adhering to SOLID principles, or some how better in any way to use `ICollection<T>` over `IList<T>`?

**EDIT:**

The duplicate question's answers do not answer my question since they avoid talking about the fact that `ICollection<T>` can do what `IList<T>` does but in a much uglier way.

If they both do the same thing, why not just use the cleaner `IList<T>`?

I received much better answers here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/dl9xao/why_use_icollectiont_over_ilistt/

Comment: So you're saying that I can call your method or read your property, get back a list, and then start adding elements to it?

Comment: The 3 types involved in your question tells me different things. IEnumerable tells me that I will get a collection of items. ICollection tells me I will get a collection of items that guarantees easy and quick access to the number of items in it. List tells me I will get a collection I can manipulate. You will have to decide which level is appropriate in each case.

Comment: But ICollection gives you a collection you can manipulate as well. ICollection just seems like it has all the same functionality as IList, just not as clean.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel this question is off topic because it indirectly asks for peoples opinion and suggestion. There is no fixed solid single answer that says "return this when that otherwise this other thing". I have several opinions just on whether you should return one or the other, depending on a lot of factors but it boils down to being *my* opinions.

Comment: You're right, but it doesn't have to be a list. It can be something else that allows you to manipulate it. I guess I confused it with IReadOnlyCollection which is the one I use, sorry about that.

Comment: Where should I go to ask a question that involves getting people's opinions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning 'IList' vs 'ICollection' vs 'Collection'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855693/returning-ilist-vs-icollection-vs-collection)

Comment: To get peoples opinions I always feel the chat rooms here would solve that. There might be other sites in the network that handles it better though, but I tend to go to the chatrooms. You can find them top right in the small Stack Exchange button.

Comment: My opinion about the types involved is that you should be as open as possible in input parameters/positions, which means favor IEnumerable over ICollection/List, and as explicit as possible in output parameters/positions. For instance, if your method *constructs* a new list and fills it with new data, what harm does it do to return it? But also consider API evolution, do you want to limit yourself to *always* have to return a list in the future? No easy discussions I'm afraid.

Comment: I think your question is actually a duplicate and is addressed by those answers (broadly) -  It's a use case scenario.  One such scenario is using `IDictionary` or `dynamic` types (`System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`) for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking at this from an overhead perspective, I think you're best bet is the intermediary between the two, [`ISet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iset-1) and it's implementation of `HashSet<T>`.

Set's are often overlooked, but are extremely efficient in determining "ownership" and save space by virtue of not relying on keys since they don't concern themselves with ordering.

> *EDIT (2020/11/18)* - **It's important to note** that upon adding an item to the HashSet, it's HashCode will be computed. The cost of this might be expensive, and thus complete negate any performance benefits you might gain from faster lookups.

The important difference is that `Add()`, `Remove()` and `Contains()` all become o(1) (vs the typically o(n) cost of `IList<T>`.

There is also `SortedSet<T>` if ordering becomes an issue.

Here's a great [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/02/03/c.net-little-wonders-the-useful-but-overlooked-sets.aspx) explaining this is much better depth than I can. An important snippet:

> The `HashSet<T>` is the set of choice if you want the fastest possible lookups but don’t care about order.  In contrast the `SortedSet<T>` will give you a sorted collection at a slight reduction in performance.

Comment: Some misleading information here -- hashsets, while excellent for fast lookup, are not always better.  You need to keep in mind that adding something to a hashset requires the item's hash to be computed, which, depending on the particular use case, may completely negate any lookup performance benefits.  Understand it and use it wisely...

Comment: If you read carefully I don't claim that HashSet's are a silver bullet as your implying. I specify the value they can bring in a particular use case, even outlining the cases where there are optimal.

Comment: Upon rereading it carefully, I still do not see any implied drawbacks of the HashSet<T>.  But, this should be easy to remedy.  I'd be happy to upvote once you update it to give a more balanced view.  HashSets are indeed frequently overlooked and your contribution on this point is very welcome!

Comment: @IgorPashchuk updated to include your note about hashcodes

Answer (score 2):

The answer is highly subjective. It's more about how much you need.

- If all you need is to loop through all the items, prefer `IEnumerable<T>`
- If you need to manupulate the collection (`Add`, `Remove` etc.) `ICollection<T>` should be used.
- If you are going to use Index frequently, use `IList<T>`.
- If you are planning to do all sort of manipulation go ahead and use `List<T>`.

However in those cases, there are `IReadonlyCollcetion<T>` and `IReadonlyList<T>`, this makes the returned collection immutable and again should come after IEnumerable but preferred over `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>`.

The end goal always is to use as abstract types as possible. This is based on the principles `Code for the interfaces not for the implementation`.

Edit: For this question I would say need of indexing is the primary factor of preferring one over other.

Comment: Controversial opinion. I ask for `IReadOnlyCollection` when I mean to iterate the enumerable more than once. I also make enumerables that can't be iterated more than once.

Comment: Multiple enumerations as well as unordered enumeration `IReadOnlyColection` will really be better. analogous answer would be, if it is foreach always IEnumerable works, if a for  loop, then `IReadOnlyCollection`. But again even though for loop can do everything that foreach does, we use foreach wherever possible.

Answer (score -1):

The short response is that you can just use IList for any list of elements. In fact, IList implements ICollection and ICollection implements IEnumerable. You're able to decide what level of abstraction you need according to the context.

See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) for details.

Comment: well... I'm not going to downvote you (given your rep), but the question statement here reflects the title: "What scenario would it be ... better ... to use `ICollection<T>` over `IList<T>`.  So, this answer doesn't really relate to the question, nor inquiry.

Comment: Also, you should probably use terms like 'implements' or even 'derives' instead of subinterface to relate to the OOP material we're more accustomed to.  Additionally, It questionable whether you should think of interfaces in a hierarchical manner.   I haven't actually delved into it enough to give certainty here, but it comes down to whether you're able to determine, during runtime, whether there is a derived interface of the base interface of an instance of some type; if it's possible to do that, I could see merit in thinking in those terms.

Comment: Thanks @brett-caswell for your comment. Updated the answer accordingly.