# Instantiate empty IQueryable for use with Linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

I need to be able to either have an optional parameter in a Linq query, or be able to assign the query to a var in something like an IF if that optional parameter needs to be removed from the query.

If I set the query var inside the IF statement then it tells me that the var doesn't exist in context when I try to loop through it.

```csharp
if (whichGroup == "All")
{
    var listOppLineData = (from o in db.opportunity_vws
                           where o.fiscal_yr_and_qtr == qtr
                           select o
                          );
}
else
{
    var listOppLineData = (from o in db.opportunity_vws
                           where o.fiscal_yr_and_qtr == qtr && o.Group == whichGroup
                           select o
                          );
}
            
foreach (var data in listOppLineData)  //listOppLineData doesn't exist here
{
 ...
```

I need to set the var before the IF statement I think, but I don't know what to set it to.

```
var listOppLineData = ""; // gives me 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Forecast.Models.opportunity_vw>' to 'string'

IQueryable listOppLineData = new IQueryable(); //gives me
        Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this:

```
IQueryable<opportunity_vw> listOppLineData;
```

This is defining the variable, but you are waiting to initialise it.

Also, looking at your query, you could do it all in one, like so:

```
var listOppLineData = (from o in db.opportunity_vws
                      where o.fiscal_yr_and_qtr == qtr && (o.Group == whichGroup || whichGroup == "All")
                      select o
                      );
```

Comment: That did the trick!! Thanks a bunch.  I wasn't as clear as I should have been in the question either.  By whichGroup == ALL I needed to query for whichGroup = anything, but I don't know how to do that in SQL.

Comment: @user2073077 Simon's code does exactly that. Notice that if `whichGroup == "All"`, then the value of `o.Group` doesn't actually matter and that part of the condition will be always `true`. (Though I have no idea if your SQL server is smart enough to realize that.)

Answer (score 265):

Try this. You can create a generic type with **T** or a specific type by replacing **T** with your type name.

```
IQueryable listOppLineData = Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable();
```

Comment: while the accepted answer helps the OP make his code "better", I truly needed to do instantiate an empty `IQueryable` and not have it set to `null`. This truly answers the OP's question of  "I need to set the var before the IF statement I think, but I don't know what to set it to."

Comment: Why not use this: IQueryable<T> hierarchies = new List<T>().AsQueryable();

Comment: @darkenergy because `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` does not create an object and avoids Garbage Collection. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/1894038/19112855

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that when you declare a variable in C#, you declare it only in the current scope. So, if you declare the variable `listOppLineData` in the `if` block, you can use it only inside that block, but not anywhere else. (You can define another variable with the same name in another block, but it would be a completely different variable, so it wouldn't have the value you assigned to the first variable.)

As you already figured out, you need to declare the variable outside the `if` blocks.

Your first attempt didn't work, because the compiler saw that you didn't explicitly specify the type of the variable (that's what `var` does) and you assigned a `string` to the variable. So it inferred that the type of the variable is `string`. And you can't assign something that is not a `string` to such variable.

Your second attempt didn't work, because you can't create an instance of an interface. (If you want to create an instance, it has to be some specific type, usually a class.) And even if you fixed that, the non-generic `IQueryable` doesn't know the type of items in it, so the `foreach` wouldn't work well.

But you don't need to assign any value to the variable, since it's assigned in both branches of the `if`. And the correct type here is the generic `IQueryable<T>`, with `T` being `opportunity_vw`. That means the correct code is:

```
IQueryable<opportunity_vw> listOppLineData;

if (whichGroup == "All")
{
    listOppLineData = …;
}
else
{
    listOppLineData = …;
}

foreach (var data in listOppLineData)
{
    …
}
```

If you really wanted to assign some value to the variable (although there is no reason to do that here), you could use `null` (which represents no value):

```
IQueryable<opportunity_vw> listOppLineData = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

For me answer was to set to empty from existing query and be able to call async without exception , if it was transformed to enumerable:

`query1 = query1.Take(0);`

It was used to union 2 queries from different tables in one common object and one of them could became empty in some validation cases. If I move first query from union to Enumerable I will get exception, if it will be called with async function(ToListAsync()), when called union:

```
var res = (await query1
    .Select(q1=> new NewClass(q1))
    .ToListAsync())
    .Union(query2
    .Select(q2=> new NewClass(q2)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding .ToList();

```
var listOppLineData = (from o in db.opportunity_vws
                                   where o.fiscal_yr_and_qtr == qtr
                                   select o
                                  ).ToList();
```

#### Update

And fix the query.

You will not have anything to iterate over without the .ToList();

#### Head Out of Butt Update

```
var listOppLineData = (from o in db.opportunity_vws
                      where (whichGroup == "All" || o.Group == whichGroup)
                      && (o.fiscal_yr_and_qtr == qtr)
                      select o);
```

Put your 'short' before the OR, so then the second part is never evaled if not needed.  I would still use the .ToList() though.

Comment: That's nonsense. 1. `ToList()` won't fix anything here. 2. You certainly can iterate `IQueryable<T>` without calling `ToList()` (because it inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`).

Comment: Good catch.  I think I misread this question several times now.

Comment: BTW, the order of evaluation shouldn't matter here, since the code is actually not executed, it's converted to SQL.

Comment: Put it in LINQPad and see.

Comment: You mean I should create a database that first this model and then look at the generated SQL?

Answer (score -1):

Specifically answering the Title and also the question:  Instantiate empty IQueryable for use with Linq to sql.  And answers the question I wound up here for, which was how to populate this thing with data for tests.

.AsQueryable() is the answer you seek.  We can turn those IEnumerables into IQueryables using that alone.  We can even populate them.

```
//An empty one might be as simple as: resulting in an IQueryable
var listOppLineData = new List<opportunity_vw>().AsQueryable();

//A populated one might be as simple as:
IQueryable<opportunity_vw> listOppLineData = 
new List<opportunity_vw>() { 
new opportunity_vw() { fiscal_yr_and_qtr = 1, Group = 2} 
}.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: It's probably downvoted because the best answer was already given in the [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29430798/861716). New answers that don't tell anything new are not well-received on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @GertArnold  perhaps I was just being obtuse.  I was seeking a way to populate a Queryable.  I suppose the answer of being an Empty<T> of an Enumerable .AsQueryable should have allowed me to infer the answer to my own dilemma.  Unfortunately, my zombie brain did not compute, so I wrote an answer that I could review for myself for the future.  The wording of the answer sometimes helps the daft.  If not, why ever look at different answers at all?

Answer (score -3):

You can use declaration like this:

```
var listOppLineData = (object)null;
```

Then use that variable as:

```
listOppLineData = (from o in db.opportunity_vws
    where o.fiscal_yr_and_qtr == qtr && (o.Group == whichGroup || whichGroup == "All")
    select o
);
```

Comment: Please no, it's absolutely no improvement to use `object` here. Now how to use  `listOppLineData` in the rest of the code?

Comment: you can use it directly with the variable name 'listOppLineData '. I used this a lot in my web APIs projects and did not have issue yet .

Comment: I think the question is, how do you use it as anything other than a list of objects? That's less than helpful!